# Splitting by multiple separator and keep separator

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string inputs:

```
"11A4B"
"5S6B"
```

And want the following outputs:

```
["11A", "4B"]
["5S", "6B"]
```

Eg after each delimiter A, B or S split and keep the delimiter.

I can do with `split` from `re` (putting parenthesis on the delimiter pattern returns also the delimiter used):

```
re.split("([ABS])", "11A4B")
#['11', 'A', '4', 'B', '']
```

And can play around to have the wanted solution but I wonder if there is a pure regex solution?

Comment: What is the Python version? With PyPi regex module, you may do that with "pure" regex. Python 3.7 also has a fixed `re.split` method to be used with `(?<=[ABS])(?!$)`.

Comment: The version used is Python 3.6

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Saw your comment a bit too late.

Comment: Then you need a workaround, e.g. `re.findall(r'(?=.)[^ABS]*[ABS]?', s)`.

Comment: Well, if you do not mind empty elements, [`re.findall(r'[^ABS]*[ABS]?', s)`](https://regex101.com/r/pGZQIU/1) will do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution that will work in all Python versions will be the one based on PyPi `regex` module with `regex.split` and `regex.V1` flag:

```
import regex
ss = ["11A4B","5S6B"]
delimiters = "ABS"
for s in ss:
    print(regex.split(r'(?<=[{}])(?!$)'.format(regex.escape(delimiters)), s, flags=regex.V1))
```

[Output](http://rextester.com/IXVDL37678):

```
['11A', '4B']
['5S', '6B']
```

**Details**

- `(?<=[ABS])` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with `A` , `B` or `S`
- `(?!$)` - and that is not immediately followed with the end of string (so, all locations at the end of the string are failed).

The `regex.escape` is used just in case there may be special regex chars in the delimiter list, like `^`, `\`, `-` or `]`.

In [Python 3.7, `re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) also can split with zero-length matches, so, the following will work, too:

```
re.split(r'(?<=[{}])(?!$)'.format(re.escape(delimiters)), s)
```

Else, you may use workarounds, like

```
re.findall(r'[^ABS]*[ABS]?', s) # May result in empty items, too
re.findall(r'(?s)(?=.)[^ABS]*[ABS]?', s) # no empty items due to the lookahead requiring at least 1 char
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pGZQIU/2).

**Details**

- `(?s)` - `.` matches newlines, too
- `(?=.)` - one char should appear immediately to the right of the current location
- `[^ABS]*` - any 0+ chars other than `A`, `B` and `S`
- `[ABS]?` - 1 or 0 (=optional) `A`, `B` or `S` char.

Answer (score 3):

Use `re.findall` instead, and match digits followed by either `A`, `B`, or `S`:

```
re.findall(r'\d+[ABS]', '11A4B')
```

Output:

```
['11A', '4B']
```

If the input might have other alphabetical characters as well, then use a negated character set instead:

```
re.findall(r'[^ABS]+[ABS]', 'ZZZAYYYSXXXB')
```

Output:

```
['ZZZA', 'YYYS', 'XXXB']
```

Comment: Since I have only digits it works! was the other way round , thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use lookarounds:

```
(?<=[ABS])(?!$)
```

Se [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/9g64oU/1).

Comment: So, it won't work with python 3.6 `re`. It will only work with `regex` module if you use a specific flag

Answer (score 1):

Use `findall`:

```
re.findall('(.*?(?:[ABS]|.$))', "11A4B5")
```

Comment: seems naughty, could you elaborate?

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel: Problem with CertainPerformance's solution are consecutive delimiters and everything after the last delimiter. `.*?` takes zero or more characters up to the next delimiter, `|.$` takes everything after the last delimiter.